# Confused if WebJob is failing or not

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

Just created a new WebJob that runs every two hours and I'm confused if it's succeeding or failing.

It makes an API call to a third party app and processes some data internally based on the API call results. Currently, no data available on third party API so I can't tell if it's truly failing or not.

As you can see, the bird's eye view shows it as failing -- see below:
[image]

If I click the particular run that seems to have failed, I get this screen which is even more confusing. At the top, it says failed but right next to the actual run, it shows success. Which is the case here?

[image]

Comment: Are you running continuous or on demand? How are you triggering the webjob? Timertriggers?